# Origin of the term "Predicate" to refer to a boolean function?

Tags: scheme, predicate

In Scheme, the term "predicate" is used [as follows](http://web.mit.edu/scheme_v9.0.1/doc/mit-scheme-ref/Equivalence-Predicates.html):

> A predicate is a procedure that always returns a boolean value (#t or #f).

Why does scheme use "predicate" to refer to such a function? And if the usage comes from a previous language, what was the motivation for selecting this term in the first place?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, this comes from mathematical logic, as [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_%28mathematical_logic%29) says, predicate is a fundamental concept in first-order logic. In every "implementation" of logic, predicate is a sentence that is either true or false - so it fits into programming languages very well.